# Best way to authenticate users?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, security, session, cookies

I realize this question maybe subjective, but I'm fairly new at this and while there is A LOT on this subject. I’ve yet to be able to form a good opinion on this and I'm thinking that maybe due in part that because I'm new I can only think in terms of my project, which isn’t anything out of the ordinary.

So I’m asking in my environment what is the best option for authentication? What method is best sessions? cookies? Something else? Also how do you save passwords in a table safely? I researched data types, but that seem to yield any help.  Is there something special that you have to do the table and/or column? Eventually I would love to add other authentication methods to my site {ie Facebook, Google, OpenID}, but I think I need to understand this first.

My environment is ASP.NET with the code behind in VB.  I am using MSSQL 2005 (But have access to 2008 if need be).

Thanks
Josh

Comment: Answer: Use ASP.Net's built-in membership system. (or the newer SimpleMembership)

Comment: If you are using VS2012, those other authentication methods are built in so you can implement with 0 effort. Well, you have to uncomment out some lines.

Comment: Eh. Yeah I looked into that. But it seems too convoluted and hard to manage programmatically. But I think it would be a good tool if it was easy to use. How do you save authentication (cookie/session/somethingelse?) What is SimpleMembership?

Comment: Definitely use the built in membership system if you are not absolutely sure what you are doing here to avoid security problems - under the hood this will use cookies as a token to authenticate the user when requesting content. If you do write your own provider then session will need to be maintained using cookies, you should never use query string parameters as an authentication token. In a corporate environment you might want to use the Active Directory membership provider.

Comment: So can someone point me to how to customize the requirements for the built-in membership system?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with ASP, so I can't answer you on how best to communicate and keep the credentials throughout the session.  It sounds like using the built-in membership system, as others have suggested, is the safest approach.  I totally sympathize, however, with your desire to do things yourself and understand how they are working under-the-hood.  If you do want to tackle doing this yourself, I can speak to the database side of things.

If at all possible, don't ever store the actual password anywhere.  You should only be storing an irreversibly-encrypted value generated from the password (using a hash-encryption algorithm such as [SHA512Managed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha512managed.aspx)).  To authenticate the user, rather than decrypting the stored password and comparing the two plain-text passwords, you want to encrypt the entered password and then compare the two encrypted values.  If you store the actual password, even if it's encrypted with a reversible-encryption algorithm, it is a big security risk.

Also, if you are using an encryption algorithm that allows you to specify a seed value, you should use an algorithm to generate the seed value based on the original password.  You don't want to use the same encryption-seed value for every password.

Also, most encryption methods are designed to be fast so that they can be used for communication streams.  However, if they are fast, that means someone can brute-force crack them more quickly.  Therefore, the best method for making your encryption safer is to make them as slow as is reasonably possible.  Often this is accomplished by re-encrypting the encrypted value over and over again in a loop for a fixed number of times.

Comment: Exactly Steven, I want to know the ‘science’ behind it all. Not to mention I feel like the build-ins are too cumbersome and hard to manage. I’ve tried customizing the info and difficult. But, then again I'm new and might be missing something. But you are correct. I would much rather do it myself if for any other reason, to learn. 

You have enlightened me a great deal! 

Now on to ASP part… hopefully!

Comment: Yes, using provided features, like that, is great, but I've been bitten enough times in the past to at least be cautious about doing so.  Writing something yourself may take longer, but in the end, you fully understand how it works, so when something goes wrong, you know how to fix it.  Also, you don't have to write hacks around it to make it work the way you want it to work.  I know nothing about this "membership" feature, but if its anything like any other security-related feature coming out of Redmond, I can easily imagine just how convoluted and cumbersome it might be.

Comment: That being said, it's still a good idea to learn the tools, like that, which are provided in the framework and use them judiciously in the areas where they make sense.  If all you need is a simple authentication mechanism with no out-of-the-ordinary requirements, its probably best to use what's already there, or at least wrap it inside a more friendly "sheath" interface.

Comment: Thanks again Steven. I found an awesome post over the weekend that explained the VB site of things.  || http://bit.ly/NcCH1z || With your explaination of DB and this site i think i'm well on my way. THANKS!